# Reducing constructor boiler plate code

Tags: c#

I often end up writing classes like this:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }

    public Animal(Dog data)
    {
        this.Colour = data.Colour;
        this.Weight = data.Weight;
    }

    public Animal(Cat data)
    {
        this.Colour = data.Colour;
        this.Weight = data.Weight;
    }
}
```

When you have lots of properties and types then you quickly end up with a lot of boiler plate code. Ideally in this situation I would just create an IAnimal interface and reference that. I'm currently in a situation where the Dog and Cat classes exist in a third party assembly and I can't modify them. The only solution that I can come up with is:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }

    public Animal(Cat data){Init(data);}
    public Animal(Dog data){Init(data);}

    private void Init(dynamic data)
    {
        this.Colour = data.Colour;
        this.Weight = data.Weight;
    }
}
```

This works but I lose all type safety, is there a better solution than constructor injection?

Thanks,

Joe

EDIT: Here is a real world example. I have a third party library which returns 3 objects called:

- GetPageByIdResult
- GetPagesByParentIdResult
- GetPagesByDateResult

(These are all auto generated classes from a service reference and the properties are pretty much identical)

Instead of dealing with these three objects I want to deal with a single PageData object or a collection of them.

Comment: Looks like a strange class, why isn't Cat and Dog inheriting from Animal?

Comment: if `Dog` and `Cat` inherit from `Animal`, you can try: `public Animal(Anima data)`

Comment: Copy Constructor on the base/parent object definitely shouldn't cater for all the cases of its derived types. Also, if `Cat` and `Dog` inheriting from `Animal` you can do perfectly well with a single constructor with an `Animal` parameter.

Comment: This is typical use for design pattern Factory

Comment: You can always use the builder pattern, so this pattern is used to separate construction logic from the data structure!

Comment: Also I don't believe that is constructor injection, that typically refers to Dependency Injection when we want to achieve inversion of control.

Comment: To be honest this is a strange example because it doesn't quite show what you're trying to achieve, it feels a bit like xy solution...

Comment: ok so what you worry about loosing type safety or ugly boiler plate code?

Comment: How about using a library like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or reflection to set properties based on matching names?

Comment: @A.T. this isn't an "either/or" situation.  You CAN successfully interopt with a third party library while both maintaining type safefy AND reducing boilerplate code.

Comment: i wish we had generic constructor for this purpose. but i think you can use generic class anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the logic in one common constructor that all the other constructors call:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }

    public Animal(Dog data) : this (data.Colour, data.Weight)
    {
    }

    public Animal(Cat data) : this (data.Colour, data.Weight)
    {
    }

    private Animal(string colour, int weight)
    {
        this.Colour = colour;
        this.Weight = weight;
    }
}
```

This is pretty similar to your second solution but it doesn't lose type safety.

Comment: Ah, good idea. This seems like the best solution so far but I'll wait till tomorrow before accepting.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm currently in a situation where the `Dog` and `Cat` classes exist in a
>   third party assembly and I can't modify them

I'd suggest Automapper-based solution:

```
public static class AnimalFactory
{
    public static Animal Create<T>(T source)
        where T : class
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<T, Animal>();
        return Mapper.Map<Animal>(source);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        var catAnimal = AnimalFactory.Create(cat);
        var dogAnimal = AnimalFactory.Create(dog);
```

Of course, you can provide a way to custom mapping configuration, if needed.

Comment: Hmm, this still doesn't guarantee type safety unless you have 1 method per type.

Comment: Not only that, but if there are additional properties that AutoMapper doesn't know about, this will blow sky-high at runtime.  Since the classes live externally, that could lead to a large amount of `.Ignore()` configuration, which makes this less elegant.

Comment: @DavidG: that's true. Automapper, unfortunately, hasn't option to turn off type conversion. Another option is self-made mapping tool, which could be rather difficult to write.

Comment: @DavidL: not exactly. Automapper (at least 4.0.4), just ignores extra properties from both sides (either source, or target), until you don't call `AssertConfigurationIsValid`.

Comment: @Dennis fair enough.  That didn't used to be the case but that sounds like a wonderful change.  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to have the class littered like that you can try Extension methods?

```
public static Animal ToAnimal(this Dog item)
{
    return new Animal() {Weight = item.Weight, Colour = item.Colour};
}

public static Animal ToAnimal(this Cat item)
{
    return new Animal() {Weight = item.Weight, Colour = item.Colour};
}
```

Comment: Could you also show a generic one with an interface backing both `Cat` and `Dog` cause then you can show real power with extension methods

Comment: @CallumLinington He mentions that they are in a third party library though. So how can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

try using json serializer's, with that we can ensure type safety.

```
 public class Animal
    {
        public string Colour { get; set; }
        public long Weight { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Animal Create<T>(T anyType)
        {
            return GetObject<T, Animal>(anyType);
        }
        public K GetObject<T, K>(T type1)
        {
            try
            {
                var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(type1);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<K>(serialized);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return default(K);
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Animal obj = new Animal();
            var animal = obj.Create(new  { Colour = "Red", Weight = 100 });
            //here you can pass any object, only same name properties will be initialized..
            Console.WriteLine(animal.Colour + " :  " + animal.Weight);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```